# CSV Splitter for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an application or a command that could to split a csv (preserving the a table header) into smaller equal parts?

I'm trying to import a large 36mb file and the importer is going kaputz.

Here's an example of a windows application: 
http://download.fyxm.net/CSV-Splitter-33994.html

I guess i could use wine to use this program but would prefer something native of ubuntu.

Comment: Could explain better, preferably with an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [csvfix.](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/)

It's a command line tool for managing CSV files. The download page doesn't have any Linux binaries, but you can compile the source code from a makefile.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/wiki/Commands) is a list of commands. In particular, the `file_split` command looks to be what you're after.

The manual for csvfix can be found [here.](http://csvfix.byethost5.com/csvfix.htm)

Comment: How would you go ahead an compile this?

Comment: Download the version 1.1 source code [here.](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/downloads/detail?name=csvfix_src_110a.zip&can=2&q=) Extract the zip archive. Open a terminal and `cd` to the extracted directory. Run `make lin` to compile the program. The `csvfix` binary will be in `csvfix-build/csvfix/bin`. You can run it from that directory with `./csvfix` or copy it to `/usr/local/bin` where you'll have access to it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

So you want to have multiple files which contain part of the entries in the main file and each contains the table header?

If that is what you want, one could write a simple script that takes the first file and the number of files that you want (or the number of lines in each file) and creates those files.

If it does not need to be graphical and you tell me what parameters you want to set, I can try to make such a script for you.

---

This is my quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import optparse
import sys
import os

parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="csv-splitter infile", description="Takes a CSV file and splits it into smaller files. The header of the infile is written to each file.")
parser.add_option("-p", "--parts", dest="parts", type="int", default=3, help="number of resulting files")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
del parser

infile = args[0]

lines = 0

if not os.path.exists(infile):
    print "file does not exist"
    sys.exit(1)

print "counting lines ..."
with open(infile) as h:
    for line in h:
        lines += 1

lines_per_file = lines/options.parts
print "found %d lines, that makes %d lines per file" % (lines, lines_per_file)

with open(infile) as h:
    header = h.readline()
    read = h.readline()
    for filenumber in xrange(options.parts):
        written_lines = 0
        print "writing to file %d of %d ..." % (filenumber+1, options.parts)
        with open(infile+"-part-"+str(filenumber)+".csv", "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(header)
            while read != '' and (written_lines <= lines_per_file or filenumber+1 == options.parts):
                outfile.write(read)
                written_lines += 1
                read = h.readline()

print "done"
```

Comment: Yes that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: Which option do you need, how many files or how many lines per file? Is command line okay?

Comment: This 1 file should be split into 3 parts (currently 36mb). It's 70,000 lines. So hopefully each file is around 10mb.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: no need to! I think i found something someone wrote already. See the answer above.

Comment: Too late, already programmed something.

Comment: python has a csv module that you may find convenient.

Comment: Note, this script will probably break if there are cells with '\n' inside. Please use `csv` module, which is simple to use and will handle this case very well.

Comment: Sorry, I did not think of non-easy cases at all. But there is an answer with a real tool for this job. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I also made an online version that allows splitting by lines, file size, or file count. It's quite intuitive and user-friendly.

[CSV Live Splitter](http://www.csvlivesplitter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I made one because I wanted an online one I could use on my mac..

check [this](http://www.promotional-products.org/automatic-online-csv-file-splitter.html)